# Window.location.href() redirection

Tags: ajax, cakephp

```
Ajax redirection in success response 

success: function(json) {
if(json.status == "success")
{
       window.location.href = "<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'Dashboard', 'action' => 'index')); ?>";
}
```

I am trying to redirect the page in ajax success response, It is redirecting properly. but I want the page to be open on new window. How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.open(
 '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'Dashboard', 'action' => 'index')); ?>',
 '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
```

Comment: Wow I replaced the path to the manual path and it worked. Thanks